# Kotlin Firebase UserAuthentication need assistance

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Hey Guys Im trying to push the user data in kotlin to firebase but when i click the create account button nothing happends here is the code for Create account class

```
class CreateAccount : AppCompatActivity() {
var mAuth:FirebaseAuth?=null
var mdata:DatabaseReference?=null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account)
    mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    Createacc.setOnClickListener{
        var email=acemail.text.toString().trim()
        var pass=acpass.text.toString().trim()
        var name=acname.text.toString().trim()

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)||!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)||!TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)){
            createAccount(email,pass,name)
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please fill all the details",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}

fun createAccount(email: String,password:String,dispname:String){

    mAuth!!.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this,{
          task: Task<AuthResult> ->
        if(task.isSuccessful){
            var curruser=mAuth!!.currentUser
            var userid=curruser!!.uid
            Toast.makeText(this,"Building user wait",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            var uobject=HashMap<String,String>()
            uobject.put("Display_name",dispname)
            uobject.put("Status","Hi I'm New")
            uobject.put("image","default")
            uobject.put("thumb image","default")

            mdata=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(userid)
            mdata!!.setValue(uobject).addOnCompleteListener{
                task:Task<Void>  ->
                if(task.isSuccessful){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"User Created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"OOPS!! User not Created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

}
Main problem is in create account function ,it is being called correctly but right after the createUserWithEmailAndPassword  function the task is not successfull hence the if loop does not run. There nothing is printed in the toast Neither "User created " nor "OOPS not created" i dont know whats going on.
I have installed the firebase dependency and my app is connected to a firebase database.

Comment: Have you tried to use `mAuth` instead of `mAuth!!`? Have you also tried to add the else part and print `task.getException()`? What does it print?

Comment: Yeah Didnt work but i just noticed when i click create account button there is a warning icon which says update google play services

Comment: So the Google Services was the problem.

Comment: How can i update it sorry i'm still new to android

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup